# How to use declarativeWebRequest with onAuthRequired to fill out credentials?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, coffeescript

In my extension I'm currently using `chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener` to catch proxy authentication dialogs and fill in credentials:

*Coffeescript:*

```
chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(handleAuthRequest, 
   {urls: ["<all_urls>"]}, ["asyncBlocking"])


handleAuthRequest = (details, callback) ->
  console.debug "AuthRequest received", details

  credentials:
    username: 'user'
    password: 'password'

  callback credentials
```

This works fine.
But when the browser is restarted and the plugin is not fully loaded a dialog will appear ([which is a known bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=328904)).

---

In a google group someone mentioned to use the new `declarativeWebRequest` API which is blocking on browser start.

This is my current implementation:

```
registerRules = ->
  changeRule =
    id: 'auth'
    priority: 100

    # If any of these conditions is fulfilled, the actions are executed.
    conditions: [new chrome.declarativeWebRequest.RequestMatcher(stages: ["onAuthRequired"])]
    actions: [new chrome.declarativeWebRequest.SendMessageToExtension(message: 'authRequest')]

  callback = ->
    if chrome.extension.lastError
      console.error "Error adding rules: " + chrome.extension.lastError
    else
      console.info "Rules successfully installed"
      chrome.declarativeWebRequest.onRequest.getRules null, (rules) ->
        console.info "Now the following rules are registered: " + JSON.stringify(rules, null, 2)


  chrome.declarativeWebRequest.onRequest.addRules [changeRule], callback
  chrome.declarativeWebRequest.onMessage.addListener (details) ->
    console.info details

registerRules()
```

The `onAuthRequired` stage condition does work as expected but I'm struggling to find a way to respond to the auth request with credentials.

According to the [Documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest.html#evaluation) the supported actions for onAuthRequest are `CancelRequest`, `IgnoreRules` and `SendMessageToExtension`.

The first two actions are definitely not the right choice but as `SendMessageToExtension` doesn't provide a callback, **how can I provide credentials for an authentication request then**?

Thanks!

---

Update:

Actually it seems like additionally the `onAuthRequired` is not correctly fired, when I replace the condition with this one:

```
conditions: [new chrome.declarativeWebRequest.RequestMatcher(contentType: ["text/html"])]
```

then the onMessage listener below is being fired correctly, with onAuthRequired it's not.

```
chrome.declarativeWebRequest.onMessage.addListener (details) ->
console.warn "onMessage fired", details
```

Answer (score 0):

Noone suggested a clean solution in 6 years so here is a duck tape I'm using:

I was struggling with proxy authorization popup on the start for a while.

Eventually I ended up with delay initialization of `chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener` and `chrome.proxy.settings.set` like this:

```js
var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
          singleProxy: {
            scheme: "%protocol",
            host: "%proxy_host",
            port: parseInt(%proxy_port)
          },
          bypassList: ["l"]
        }
      };

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%username",
            password: "%password"
        }
    };
}

setTimeout(function () {
    chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
        callbackFn,
        {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
        ['blocking']
    );

    chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});    
}, 1500); // proxy will be set in a 1.5 sec after the browser start
```

In my case this is used in Selenium tests so I'm totally in control of the first 1.5 seconds and I can grant this time for extension.